# MVC3 Parameters in Controller Methods Convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Quite often when writing controllers you need to use a parameter name other than the default of "id".  In this case, the lazy coder in me wants to use the old fashioned convention of using parameter1=abc but then there is a little voice in my head that says I should set up custom routes.  The question is which approach is better?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: So you still want to have id but add an extra param too. I would just add it and call as you have suggested... `webite/controller/action/1?param=abc`

Comment: Well, no I want two controller methods one which takes the id parameter and which takes just one parameter but called something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this already with the default routes but in the first case the url will be

```
website/controller/action/1
```

while on the other case the url will be

```
webite/controller/action?param=abc
```

Does this fit your needs?

The problem is that id and param cannot be of the same type. You can't declare the same action twice with the same signature.